# Deleting columns from multiple table having relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using Gridview to Display some Data from database and have giving option to delete data But now i just referenced primary key column to another table by foreign key. Anyway to delete and now delete is not working because of conflict.

> Error:-The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_temp1_ProductDetails". The conflict occurred in database
>   "E:\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\SHOPMOBILE\APP_DATA\SHOPPING.MDF", table
>   "dbo.temp1", column 'product_id'. The statement has been terminated.

Anyway to delete data from both the table on same time.Delete query is

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:shoppingConnectionString2 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ProductDetails] WHERE [Product_id] = @original_Product_id" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductDetails]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ProductDetails] SET [Product_name] = @Product_name, [Brand] = @Brand, [Category] = @Category, [Sub_category] = @Sub_category, [Product_info] = @Product_info, [Price] = @Price, [Big_img] = @Big_img, [Quantity] = @Quantity WHERE [Product_id] = @original_Product_id">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Product_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Product_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Brand" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Category" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Sub_category" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Product_info" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Int64" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Big_img" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quantity" Type="Int64" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: You have to delete the record in `temp1` that references the `ProductDetails` table before you delete the record in `ProductDetails`. Either issue separate commands in the correct order, or enable `CASCADE DELETE` on the `temp1` table's FK. And please don't leave a table called `temp1` in your project, it's no good for anyone with that name.

Comment: @Borat I want to Delete selected product from productdetails table but i liked that table to temp1 so above code is firing error as that data is present in temp1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sql server management studio, select ProductDetails table design view and open relationships window, then set delete action to CASCADE DELETE, It's works fine.
[image]

UPDATE: set it for all table relationships.

Comment: @ALOK Did you set it for all table relationships?

Comment: Ok ok this column is further referenced by another table that is Order table and thats why it is not able to delete. Thanks @Hadi for bringing some new thing for me.

Comment: @ALOK: Just be very careful with cascading deletes; you might unknowingly remove something important from your table(s). It would be better to create a stored procedure that can properly validate before performing a delete, then use that as your delete command.